# Adding empty directories to .tar file in Java using JTar

Tags: java, tar

I'm trying to package a directory, which includes an empty sub-directory, into a .tar file using Java's JTar. Folders that contain files are automatically included in the .tar file, but the empty folders are not. I want to preserve the directory structure below, is this possible?

```
MyTarFile.tar--|
               |--ChildFolder1--|
                                |--MyFile.txt
               |--ChildFolder2--|
```

> > ChildFolder1 is created, ChildFolder2 is not.

Comment: I am facing a same problem my code is: